# Batch file: evaluating command output with regex?

Tags: regex, batch-file, find

I have made a Windows batch file based on some examples I have found elsewhere.
What it does is it parses a folder for a specific file type (.mkv) and then runs mkvmerge.exe from the MKVToolNix folder.
The command produces an output, listing the different tracks in the container.

The core of the file is

```
 set rootfolder="Z:\Movies"
 for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
   for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge -i "%%a" ^| find /c /i "chapters"') do (
     if [%%b]==[0] (
       echo "%%a" has no chapters
     ) else (
       echo Doing some interesting stuff!
     )
   )
 )
```

The above example is just part of the file, rootfolder is set to the folder I want parsed, of course, and upon finding a file with chapters in it, it will run additional commands.
It all works beautifully but I also want to check for subtitles at the same time. The find command doesn't take regular expressions or I could just have added "chapters subtitles". My efforts using other commands, like findstr, haven't really worked.
How do I go about using RegEx here?

This is an example output, running mkvmerge.exe on an .mkv file

```
mkvmerge.exe -i "Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs (1937) [tt0029583].mkv"
File 'Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs (1937) [tt0029583].mkv': container: Matroska
Track ID 0: video (MPEG-4p10/AVC/h.264)
Track ID 1: audio (DTS)
Track ID 2: audio (AC-3)
Track ID 3: subtitles (HDMV PGS)
Track ID 4: subtitles (HDMV PGS)
Chapters: 26 entries
```

This example has both subtitle and chapter tracks and the batch file will find the keyword "chapters" (it's set to ignore case). I also want to catch the files that contain the keyword "subtitles" even when there are no chapters.

To clarify my intent here, I want the code to:

- Parse through the given folder
- For all .mkv files, do *mkvmerge /i* which will output (as text) the    streams in that file
- Look at that output and if it contains the word(s) "chapters" and/or    "subtitles" trigger some action.

Comment: You should provide a sample output you want to parse. Not everyone uses mkvmerge.

Comment: Thanks, I will add an example output, although I didn't find it necessary at the time of writing. The point here was to scan for either of 2 keywords instead of just one.

Comment: You should also share your (failed) `findstr` attempts...

Comment: Good point aschipfl, but since I wasn't aware of the mechanics of the for /f loop or the format of the output, they never amounted to anything but empty variables or incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to make no distinction between whether one string or the other (or both) is detected, then

```
@Echo off
set rootfolder="Z:\Movies"
for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
 mkvmerge -i "%%a" | findstr /i "^Chapters subtitles" >nul
 if errorlevel 1 (
  echo Neither Chapters nor subs found in "%%a"
 ) else (
  echo Chapters or subs found in "%%a"
 )
)
```

would likely be easier.

Comment: Spot on! That was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Took me a while until I spotted the missing ( in the if statement.

Comment: @KarstenJensen If this answer solved your issue, please select it as the correct answer by selecting the grey tick mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Still unclear how a line with `Subtitles` would look like.
Presuming the values `Chapters` and `Subtitles` appear in 1st column
The `for /f` splits the lines at colon and space (adjacent delims count as one) into tokens 1=%%b and 2=%%c the possible unsplitted rest in token 3=%%d
The space separated (ORed) RegEx search words anchored `^` at line begin will only match chapters/subtitles.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\27\SO_50555308.cmd
@Echo off
set rootfolder="Z:\Movies"
for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=: " %%b in (
        'mkvmerge -i "%%a" ^| findstr /i "^Chapters subtitles"'
    ) do (
        if /i "%%b"=="Chapters" if "%%c"=="0" (
            echo "%%a" has no chapters
        ) else (
            echo "%%a" has %%c chapters
            echo Doing some interesting stuff!
        )
        if /i "%%e"=="subtitles" echo "%%a" %%b %%b %%d: %%e %%f
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not really sure it does what I need it to do and it doesn't seem to catch subtitles at all.
I want it to look at the output of each movie file and then
If the output contains the word "subtitles" and/or "chapters", then do stuff, otherwise skip.

Comment: To parse it properly  I need a sample from subtitle you didn't provide

Comment: The example above contains 
Video track, 2 audio tracks, 2 subtitle tracks and chapters

Comment: Didn't recognize that, my anchor at line begin can't match, how do you want the output to be?

Comment: I don't really need an output. I just need a check whether a given file, based on the output from the mkvmerge command, contains either subtitle tracks and/or chapters. The problem is I'm not familiar with pipes or the for loops. If it was an IF statement I would just put OR.

Comment: I have now clarified it at the end of the post

Comment: Changed batch, give it another try, the output will be file and the line with subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks LotPings for your effort. I learned something about tokens that will be very useful. Your script also got me on the right track (learning a few more commands on the way.

Your script ended up looking like this:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\27\SO_50555308.cmd
@Echo off
set rootfolder="Z:\Movies"
for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set "found="
    for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=: " %%b in (
        'mkvmerge -i "%%a" ^| findstr /i "^Chapters subtitles"'
    ) do (
        if /i "%%b"=="Chapters" set found=1
        if /i "%%e"=="subtitles" set found=1
    )
    if defined found (
        echo Chapters or subs found in "%%a"
    ) else (
        echo.
    )
)
```

All I needed was to check whether one of my keywords were present in any of the tokens and then set a flag accordingly and after the loop do the appropriate action, resetting the flag for the next file.